# is there any class or method for getting cdma signalstrength can get for gsm but not for cdma in android?

Tags: android

is there any class or method for getting cdma signalstrength I got for gsm but not for cdma in android??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Signal Strength](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html) you can use the function: `getCdmaDbm()`